# constructing image url from known components

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails app and when someone searches for a property and then clicks to see more details I want to show them the property details and the images for that property. I've got the table figured out that contains all the property details and I've uploaded images to Amazon S3 but can't work out how to construct the image url:

All properties in the database have a sysid in the main database table, for instance, 335758034, and that sysid is included in the S3 image url and the image number is appended to the end of that url so it's possible to work out the url like so:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/images732/Photo335758034-3.jpeg

and a column in the table tells you how many images there are for a property. So if you know there's 5 images I just have to loop through them like so:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/images732/Photo + sysid-1.jpeg

https://s3.amazonaws.com/images732/Photo + sysid-2.jpeg

https://s3.amazonaws.com/images732/Photo + sysid-3.jpeg

https://s3.amazonaws.com/images732/Photo + sysid-4.jpeg

https://s3.amazonaws.com/images732/Photo + sysid-5.jpeg

How do I do that? Any help much appreciated, thanks, Adam

UPDATE:

Here's how it ended up:

```
<table summary="Property images">
    <% (1..@property.image_count).each do |photo| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/images732/Photo#{@property.sysid}-#{photo}.jpeg") %></td>
</tr>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails,

```
(1..5).each do |n|
  image_tag "https://foo.com/photo/photo-#{n}.jpg"
end
```

Of course, instead of iterating through a range as in this example, you can just loop through whatever you want instead.

Comment: but what id there is 7 images or 20 images, how do I make the range fit the number of images?

Comment: If it's a known variable count, then you can construct the range based on that count.  

If the image urls are in an array, then you can do something like: `image_urls.each { |url| image_tag url }`.

If the image length is a count, then you can build the range dynamically like: `(1..image_length).each`

Comment: yes that did it, thanks very much, I added the finished product to my question above

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using paperclip to help rails communicate directly to S3.  You could make a table that contains photos, and set the property record to has_many :photos.  It would be easy at that point to reference the collection of photos on the property object.  Something like

```
@property.photos.each do |photo|
   image_tag photo.url
end
```

That way you could have rails take care of all the background stuff.  for information using paperclip and s3 take a peek at these

http://doganberktas.com/2010/09/14/amazon-s3-and-paperclip-rails-3/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Comment: thanks for the answer, I can see how that would work but I wanted to avoid putting images in a database table, wanted to keep them in the filesystem. Good to know about the s3 gem too